# Any way to force CompositionTarget.Rendering run X frames per second?

Tags: .net, wpf

Any way to force CompositionTarget.Rendering of WPF run X frames per second? or almost this?
Thank you.

Comment: What did you try that did not work?

Comment: just to test perfomance.

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested only for performance benchmarks, don't subscribe to `Rendering` event.

It may degrade performance.

WPF goes out of its way to ensure that animations are rendered at high frame rates from a second (non-ui) thread. For example, this thread only runs unmanaged code to ensure it won't be interrupted by garbage collection.

If you subsribe to the rendering event, you require WPF to sync between your UI thread and this render thread. EDIT: If you want to change framerate, you can hint a [`DesiredFrameRate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.desiredframerate.aspx) by setting the property by that name on an animation. (Default is 60).

To see actual framerates, you can run [profiling tools](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/perf/wpf-perf-tool.aspx) like the perforator.

Comment: as this rendering has bad performance, can you suggest me another way to do please?

Comment: I don't understand how to set the fps in code behind using DesiredFrameRate. Could you explain me please?

Comment: @Alan: DesiredFrameRate is a dependency property on all animations, inherited from `Timeline`. So you can set it on a doubleanimation, for example. For the inheritance hierarchy see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.animationtimeline.aspx#inheritanceContinued

Comment: @Alan: To debug animation performance, you can see the frame rate in perforator. That also reports what kind of stuff gets rendered, which may be more than you expect. If you have a performance problem with WPF, I'd reccomend you open a new question, and post a working sample that shows the problem.